# suspicious zpool resilver

Tags: raid, storage, zfs

ZFS on linux, Ubuntu 16.04LTS. 
ZFS pool, raidz1 vdev with 5x4TB drives.

Yesterday I noticed one drive completely flaked. (Audible noise from heads attempting to reset, recalibrate). It was toast. So I offline it.

```
mrenouf@archive:~$ sudo zpool status
  pool: tank
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices has been taken offline by the administrator.
    Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue functioning in a
    degraded state.
action: Online the device using 'zpool online' or replace the device with
    'zpool replace'.
  scan: resilvered 2.42G in 0h3m with 0 errors on Thu Apr 20 08:04:09 2017
config:

    NAME                                       STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    tank                                       DEGRADED     0     0     0
      raidz1-0                                 DEGRADED     0     0     0
        ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH0ZH6V-part2  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH0Z9EG-part2  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH0ZJZS-part2  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH0ZDDJ-part2  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH0ZJDQ-part2  OFFLINE      0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

> Sidenote: Why -part2? FreeNAS did that (where this pool was originally
>   created). Each drive has a 2GB swap partition in front of the data
>   I decided it was best to replicate that on the replacement drive for
>   symmetry.

So anyway, I pop in a replacement and start the resilver.

```
zpool replace tank ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH0ZJDQ-part2 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH15ZE0-part2
```

It "finishes" in record time... (after showing an estimate in the range of 20h). I dont have the history from the intermediate steps but trust me...  There's ~4TB aollocated in this pool.

```
pool: tank
state: ONLINE
scan: resilvered 2.42G in 0h3m with 0 errors on Thu Apr 20 08:04:09 2017
  config:

    NAME                                       STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    tank                                       ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0                                 ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH0ZH6V-part2  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH0Z9EG-part2  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH0ZJZS-part2  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH0ZDDJ-part2  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH15ZE0-part2  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

**I *DON'T* believe you!**

What can cause this? What do I do now? I haven't figured out how to replace the drive with itself yet (and force another resilver).

EDIT:

I run a scrub on this new "resilvered":

```
  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices has experienced an unrecoverable error.  An
        attempt was made to correct the error.  Applications are unaffected.
action: Determine if the device needs to be replaced, and clear the errors
        using 'zpool clear' or replace the device with 'zpool replace'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-9P
  scan: scrub in progress since Thu Apr 20 08:39:31 2017
    12.1G scanned out of 4.29T at 87.7M/s, 14h13m to go
    159M repaired, 0.27% done
config:

        NAME                                       STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank                                       ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-0                                 ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH0ZH6V-part2  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH0Z9EG-part2  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH0ZJZS-part2  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH0ZDDJ-part2  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH15ZE0-part2  ONLINE       0     0 20.2K  (repairing)

errors: No known data errors
```

It seems to stall at the ~12G mark:

```
12.4G scanned out of 4.29T at 64.2M/s, 19h25m to go
```

Then it just STOPS:

```
  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices has experienced an unrecoverable error.  An
        attempt was made to correct the error.  Applications are unaffected.
action: Determine if the device needs to be replaced, and clear the errors
        using 'zpool clear' or replace the device with 'zpool replace'.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-9P
  scan: scrub repaired 164M in 0h3m with 0 errors on Thu Apr 20 08:42:50 2017
config:

        NAME                                       STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank                                       ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-0                                 ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH0ZH6V-part2  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH0Z9EG-part2  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH0ZJZS-part2  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH0ZDDJ-part2  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-ST4000DM005-2DP166_ZDH15ZE0-part2  ONLINE       0     0 21.5K

errors: No known data errors
```

WHAT? It didn't even scan the whole pool. How can it be done? There were no hardware errors so what the hell is going on? Argh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade to ZFS on Linux 0.7.0 (my issue was fixed with release candidate 3, available [here](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/releases/tag/zfs-0.7.0-rc3)). Follow [the compilation instructions](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Custom-Packages). After installation, make sure everything worked by checking your zfs and spl versions.

```
modinfo zfs | grep -iw version
modinfo spl | grep -iw version
```

I was having the exact same problem, and this is what worked for me.